# Bind query and header parameters to the same model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I'm trying to bind Query and Header parameters from a Controller action to one single model:

The request model:

```cs
public class MyRequest
{
    [FromQuery]
    public string QueryParameter { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public string HeaderParameter { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<MyResponse> FooAction(MyRequest myRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

The problem with this, is that:

1. Swagger requests to input a json:

```
{
   "QueryParameter": "string",
   "HeaderParameter": "string"
}
```

2. Even if I try to `curl` this endpoint, I get "Unsupported Media Type".

But, if I simply add [FromQuery] inside the controller's action:

```cs
public ActionResult<MyResponse> FooAction([FromQuery] MyRequest myRequest)
```

Then it works as expected. The problem with this, is that - it's not quite clear: "Why add FromQuery if you have FromHeader fields?"

I could make two separate models, one for Query parameters and another for Header parameters, but I would really like to find a way to get them both into the same model.

Comment: How do you send Request? HttpGet or HttpPost?

Comment: @SelimYıldız it's a GET

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read about [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding), or go directly to [Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) section.

**Here is a summary about model binding sources:**

By default, model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs from the following sources in an HTTP request: **Form fields**, **The request body** (for *ApiControllers*), **Route data**, **Query string parameters** and **uploaded files**.

If the default source is not correct, use one of the following attributes to specify the source: `[FromQuery]`, `[FromRoute]`, `[FromFrom]`, `[FromBody]` and `[FromHeader]`. ***IMPORTANT:*** These attributes are added to model properties individually (not to the model class).

Then the following code will work for you:

```
public IActionResult FooAction(MyRequest myRequest)
{
    return new JsonResult(myRequest);
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public string QueryParameter { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public string HeaderParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You've just copy pasted my code from the question, from what I can see. It doesn't work, at least by default. Have you tried it?
I've created a separate controller, copy-pasted your code, and I'm getting Unsupported Media Type (like the error described in my question).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,if you want to bind the data to a object in `HttpGet`,you must use a `[FromQuery]`,or it will not be binded to the object.If the data is `string myRequest` rather than `MyRequest myRequest`.You don't need  to add '[FromQuery]'.

Else, if you  use HttpPost,it also don't need '[FromQuery]':

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("FooAction")]
        public ActionResult FooAction(MyRequest myRequest)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Basically, what you're saying is that for HttpGet, I'm **required** to to add `[FromQuery] MyRequest` for that thing to work, right? Well, that is what my whole question is about: I don't want to use FromQuery for a model that has FromQuery and FromHeader. Is there a way around it?